# outerWidth equivalent in Mootools

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

Is there any equivalent of jQuery's `outerWidth` in MooTools?

I want to get `width` of block + `margin`-width + `padding`-width + `border`-width.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this function, [getComputedSize()](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Measure#Element%3agetComputedSize), in [MooTools](http://mootools.net/docs/more) More, which actually returns many dimension values.

Comment: I tried this method, but i get error when using it: getComputedSize is not a function.

Comment: because it's in [Element.Measure](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Measure) as suggested (kind of) - that's mootools-more

Comment: @Mirgorod it's in MooTools More, which you need to include…

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`Elements.Dimensions`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions) documentation.

[`getSize()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions#Element%3agetSize) is what you're looking for.

Comment: yes, but getSize gets only width without borders, paddings and margins